# Emacs: search a buffer with regex and show results in a new buffer?

Tags: regex, emacs

Supposed I had a buffer in emacs with 1000 lines, and dotted around in that buffer were unicode references (eg. `\u8226`). I want to collect all those references into another buffer, which I can then sort and uniquify.

On the (*nix) command line, I can do something like:

```
grep -o "\\\\u[0-9]*" tmpfile | sort | uniq
```

Is this achievable directly within emacs, without saving any buffers to disk?

Answer (score 6):

Go to your buffer, select it all with `C-x h`, then do `M-| grep -o "\\\\u[0-9]*" | sort | uniq` (this runs `shell-command-on-region`).  The output will go to `*Shell Command Output*`, which will not be shown unless the output is long enough, but it's always created and you can switch to it regardless.

There is also `occur` (`M-s o`).

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> M-x occur RET [[:nonascii:]]+ RET
>   M-x other-window
>   M-x toggle-read-only
>   M-x sort-lines
> ```